# How efficiently this controller action can be written more in phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I am trying to delete data from two tables which are associated with each other but I want to know that how it can be written more efficiently in phalcon as I am doing it right now through the normal PHP loop method.

Here is the Action code as :

```
  public function deletepollAction($pollId)
    {

        $poll = new Polls();
        $data = $poll->findFirst($pollId);
        $data->delete();
        $options = PollsOptions::find();
        foreach ($options as $singleoption) {
        if ($singleoption->polls_id == $pollId) 
        {
        $option = new PollsOptions();
        $data = $option->findFirst($singleoption->id);
        $data->delete();
        }
        }
        $this->response->redirect("/poll");
    }
```

I would like to know a neat and efficient and easy method to do this in phalcon model methods etc?

**Note :** It works as you can see but the problem is it messes with my executions speeds i.e (the performance of the web page goes from loading in a second to perform the action and then redirects back to the page goes to more like 2 seconds) as I would say or quite more likely from 500ms to 1000ms etc and that I do not want. I want to maintain the fast speed and to solve this issue without using the loop which in turn iterates over the records which are not related to the parent record too which wastes time.
I mean I want strictly to get all associated records from the child table and delete those directly without compromising the performance (times).

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @RobbieAverill : Thanks for your suggestion, I didn't knew about Code Review, And would it be true If I think that I may get an answer here soon than there?

Comment: You may do, but also unless you have a problem with your code this question may get closed as "off topic"

Comment: You should be using mysql triggers for deleting relevant table rows from second table. Check mysql docs for AFTER DELETE trigger creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a relationship inside the model class. You can then set cascade actions to automatically delete related records.

**Creating the relationship and setting the cascade setting**

```
class Polls extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany(
            'id',
            'PollsOptions',
            'polls_id',
            [
                'foreignKey' => [
                    'action' => \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Relation::ACTION_CASCADE
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**Updating the controller**

You no longer need to do anything other than delete the poll record.

```
public function deletepollAction($pollId)
{
    $poll = new Polls();
    $data = $poll->findFirst($pollId);
    $data->delete();
    $this->response->redirect("/poll");
}
```

Read and learn more about this here:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-models-relationships#cascade-restrict-actions

Answer (score 1):

```
public function deletepollAction($pollId)
{
    $data = Polls::findFirst($pollId);
    $data->delete();
    $options = PollsOptions::find([
        'polls_id = :pollsId:',
        'bind' => [
            'pollsId' => $pollId
        ]
    ]);
    $options->delete();
    $this->response->redirect("/poll");
}
```

Not sure why you find this `PollsOptions` once and then you find them again for deleting? It doesn't make sense. Also better just set in database to cascade delete `PollsOptions` when `Polls` is deleted then you will have only:

```
public function deletepollAction($pollId)
{
    $data = Polls::findFirst($pollId);
    $data->delete();
    $this->response->redirect("/poll");
}
```

Comment: This is also a better approach. Thanks for your answer.!